# Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

users!
I have a problem with my Microsoft VS Code.
When i run my code with method

```
System.in.read()
```

i have a problem "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended."

P.S. When i run file using javac and java this code is work.

i also have problem with VS Code [another problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37J8A.png)

My code

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class example {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws IOException {
        char symbol;
        int count = 0, count_space = 0;
        do {
            symbol = (char) System.in.read();
            if (symbol == ' ') {
                count_space += 1;
            }
            count += 1;
        } while(symbol != '.');
        System.out.println("Всего символов: " + count);
        System.out.println("Из них пробелов: " + count_space);
     }
}
```

Sorry for bad grammar.
Can you help me?

Comment: Works for me.  I think you have a problem with VS or some other part of your environment.

Comment: i know :(
it also works in online java compiler

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm a chinese student and i had the same problem. I found a solution in baidu.

The built-in debugging console of vscode does not support java input. So you need to modify the debug console in the debug configuration file (launch.json), just modify the console property from "internalConsole" to "integratedTerminal" or "externalTerminal".

Comment: Here is [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_debug-session-inputs) that confirms this answer.

Comment: i think this has gotten invalid in the meantime.