# "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended" - what does this mean in the context of my code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just recently started learning Java and I'm a bit stuck on how the Scanner class works. I used the Scanner class in my program and now my code is raising an error whenever I run it. The error is "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended" - what does this mean in the context of my code?

I developed a program which collects the user's age. In order to ensure that the user provides a number, I am using the method `.hasNextInt()`, which will continuously be checked until the user provides a number. As follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!scan.hasNextInt()){
            scan.next();
        }

        int age = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You are " + age);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

When I try to run my code, the input panel shows up (as expected), but once I provide an input, following error shows up on my screen: "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended." Why this is happening?

Comment: What IDE are you using? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279989/evaluation-failed-because-the-thread-is-not-suspended) looks similar

Comment: This has most likely something to do with your IDE, you are running or debugging your code but for some reason System.in (some command line) is not available

Answer (score 1):

This error message typically is created when running VisualStudio, and having a mis-configured java tool-chain.

What happens is you try to run the program in a debugging mode, and that mode cannot stop the execution of the program (by suspending the main Thread).  So the program runs to completion, and the IDE raises an error "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended".

But that error is an error of the IDE, and not of the program.  Your program doesn't suspend any `Threads`, if it did, you would have written it into the code.

Check that you have installed the JDK (if using older versions of Java) and not the JRE.  Also check that your integration between VS and your programming support tools (javac, javap, etc) is correct.

Or my favorite answer, use a better development environment, one that is tied to the success of Java, like `Netbeans` or `Eclipse`.  VS is tied to the success of `C#` and has some of the worst, most misleading error messages (historically, I think this was to support their claim that C# was such a better language than Java, even though it started as a clone of Java).

Answer (score 0):

Run your program from the command line:
`java test`, see if it throws the same error. If it does not - than it means that the problem is in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also confused how several of the Scanner methods work in my code. If the while loop condition (that is, !scan.hasNextInt()) has been true for several iterations, then if I provide a number, then the while loop will exit and scan.nextInt() will take this number. Can you please let me know whether this is correct?