# Code working in Python IDLE but not in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle, pylint

[image]  i created this code in my vscode to run. But it was showing error so i thought the code might be wrong so i did many changes in it. But nothing worked. Then i interpreted the same code in my idle, BOOOM! it worked, i reinterpreted it many times and it worked fine. So i want to know why is it not working in vscode. Please help me!

```
def vowel(y,z):
   if y in z:
       print("It is a vowel")
   else:
       print("It is a consonant")
z=('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')        
y=str(input("Enter a character= "))
vowel(y,z)
```

The error im getting in vscode

```
PS C:\Users\ANAND> python -u "c:\Users\ANAND\Desktop\python codes\vowel.py"
Enter a character= i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ANAND\Desktop\python codes\vowel.py", line 9, in <module>
    y=str(input("Enter a character= "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Comment: input statement will always be a string. You dont have to convert it to a string before you store into y. Just give `y=input("Enter a character= ")`

Comment: Anand, it may have to do with your vscode config. See if this link helps you get a resolution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910646/input-functionality-is-not-working-with-python-in-vscode

Comment: why is Python trying to `eval` your input string, if I run your code in VSC I can't reproduce the error

Comment: In python 2, input() is evaluated, so my guess is that your VSCode defaults to 2.7.  What does 'import sys; print(sys.version)' print?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
def vowel():
   z=('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')   
   y=str(input("Enter a character= "))
   if y in z:
       print("It is a vowel")
   else:
       print("It is a consonant")

     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    vowel()
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, it still does not solve OPs problem with input() using vscode

Comment: can u send me the image of that thing in vs code. Coz when I tried running that in vs code it was running successfully

Comment: suhail i tried running your code but it is also showing same error :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: put the variables inside the def because it cant read anything outside of the def

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with the function definition. This line of code `y=str(input("Enter a character= "))` is not working on vscode while it works on idle.

Comment: yeah i did it by writing the variables first but it is not working im receiving same error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your screenshot that the terminal uses "`Code`", but the terminal is in "Powershell" when executing the code, and the path is not the path of the currently opened file.

Please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, and then execute the code.

[image]

In addition, it is recommended that you disable the extension "code-runner" and use the cmd terminal to execute the code. (Please use `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",` in `settings.json`, then click the green button in the upper right corner to execute the code.)

[image]